# How to pass a number as a prop to a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, template-literals

I'm attempting to position a div based on the number of items inside it. I can pass the number with the props, but the template literal interpolates it as a string. Is there a way that I can have it convert this to a number to be able to properly make this calculation?

```
const BoxTray = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  bottom: calc(0 + (290px * ${props => props.contents}));
';
```

Edit: I've just noticed that nothing seems to be passing in from the prop at all... when inspecting the element, the rule shows up simply as `bottom: calc(290 * )`. This is the same whether the `px` is there or not.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve... but using 290px is a string not a number.  as for converting a string to a number you can use javascript's parseInt function.  you should probably create your own function that returns an integer

Comment: I have a cart of sorts, just the top bit of it displaying number of items in the cart. I want the cart to be positioned so that just the top is displayed (the rest hidden beneath the bottom of the viewport). I can figure out the necessary JS and CSS to reposition it so that the contents of the cart are seen if i can get this part sorted.

290px is the height of each item in the cart. So I'm trying to offset the position of the div by the total height of all items.

Comment: Multiply the 290 by the prop before adding the `px` to it. You can't multiply strings.

Comment: I've tried this. Not sure if it's just an issue with prettier (i have code formatting on save), but when I put the `px` outside the `calc()` function, prettier inserts a space between it and the function, as if it doesn't recognize it as being part of the value.

Regardless if this is the issue, no matter what I've tried, the div is sitting at the top of the page as if the bottom: rule is simply being ignored.

Comment: Why use calc at all if you have all the JS power inside template literals?

Comment: I'm realizing this. Still working through it. Though it seems now that the issue lies in the prop passing absolutely nothing to the styled component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `contents` prop is a number, you can do this.

```js
const BoxTray = styled.div`
  bottom: ${props => props.contents * 290}px;
  position: fixed;
`;
```

And then use it like:

```js
<BoxTray contents={2}>
  {/*  */}
  {/*  */}
</BoxTray>
```

Comment: This returns as `bottom: NaNpx`

Comment: @Taouen No, it doesn't. I was about to post a similar solution. You must be doing something wrong, copy and paste the code that's provided.

Comment: I did copy and paste it.

Comment: what do you pass as contents prop?

Comment: Not sure how I can show you a screenshot, but the rule in the inspector literally shows the rule as `bottom: NaNpx;`

Comment: I attempted initially passing just the number 2 as demonstrated above, and also the `contents.length` that is in my code that passes the current number of items in the array. No change between the two.

Comment: Can you share more info on how is the contents format?

Comment: Oh man I'm dumb. I was passing the prop on the wrong component. I've got it working now. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: No worries! ;-)